# All option tags that aren't selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select all `<option>` tags (`.just_added select option`) that aren't selected with jQuery.

This is what I got so far...

```
$('.just_added select option:selected');
```

The problem is that it selects all `<option>` tags that are selected, but I need to select all  `<option>` tags that aren't selected.

Any ideas? Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:not` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('.just_added select option:not(:selected)');
```

Or without jQuery pseudo selectors (using the [`.not()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method):

```
 $('.just_added select option').not(function() {
     return this.selected;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.just_added select option:not(:selected)');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) should you exactly what you want:

```
$('.just_added select option:not(:checked)');
```